# The error is "Error CS0106 The modifier 'readonly' is not valid for this item "

Tags: c#

```
namespace Practice
{
 public class LargestPrimeFactor {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        readonly long NUM = 600851475143L;
        int i;
       int n;
       int flag = 0;
       long primeFactor = 1;
       long factor = 1;
       for(i=2; i<NUM/2; i++) {
           flag = 0;
           for(n=2; n < i/2; n++) {
          if(i % n == 0) {
          flag = 1;
          }
           }
           if(flag == 0){
          factor = i;
          if(NUM % factor == 0) {
          primeFactor = factor;
          Console.WriteLine("factor = " + factor);
          }
           }
       }
       Console.WriteLine(primeFactor);
    }
}

}
```

Please explain what I’m doing wrong. I don’t know how to declare this variable so that it is read-only. When I put it outside of the method, I get different errors.

Comment: keep in mind that `const` is a compile-time constant so its hardcoded in your code while `readonly` is a run-time constant and it can be assigned via the constructor on type initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `readonly` modifier is valid at the class level, so you could refactor it as:

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {
    readonly long NUM = 600851475143L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `const` keyword either at the field level or inside a method:

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {
    const long NUM = 600851475143L;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

or

```
public class LargestPrimeFactor {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    const long NUM = 600851475143L;
        // ...
    }
}
```

`readonly` is most useful for variables that will be fully initialized before the constructor completes but don't have a constant representation, e.g.

```
readonly DateTime startedAt = DateTime.Now;
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to declare NUM as a `const` instead of a readonly.

Answer (score 0):

If you read [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly) for `readonly`, you'll see that it doesn't apply to variables declared inside a method. The keyword can only be applied to:

- [readonly field declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#readonly-field-example)
- [readonly struct definitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#readonly-struct)
- [readonly instance members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/struct#readonly-instance-members)
- [ref readonly method return](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly#ref-readonly-return-example)

If you want a variable that's defined inside a method to not be modified, you can declare it with the `const` keyword:

```
public static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    const long num = 600851475143L;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to do something similar, but for a value that was calculated at runtime.  Instead of `const long NUM = 600851475143L` I used the new(ish) local function feature - not exactly `const` or `readonly`, but a way to lock down a value

```
long NUM() => someLongRuntimeValue;
 . . .
       for(i=2; i<NUM()/2; i++) {
 . . .
```

This costs of a couple parentheses and a bit of runtime overhead - in my case the value was going to be used only a few times.  It was a defensive code practice in a module edited by many people, a way of saying "I know you might think you want to change this value, but if you do you will break things" - my future self being one of the people I'm talking to.